# How to decode special characters

Tags: objective-c, ios

i am developping an iOS application and i am using this :

```
mutableString = [mutableString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

But the problem is when my `mutableString` contain a string like this " ...a 'means of connection'..." or caracters like this one "-", the `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding` return a `null` value.

How i can decode the caracters "'" and "-"  ?? thanks

Comment: I do not see any `%` encodings in your example, post a small example of the string before you try to unescape it.

Comment: thanks for your answer : calls%20a%20%u2018means%20of%20connection%u2019%20includ

Comment: tHis one to for example : stress%20%u2013%20particularly%20tension%20%u2013%20to%20be

Comment: %uXXXX is non-standard percent encoding.

Comment: And what is the solution for this ???

Comment: You need to roll your own solution, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3556471/how-to-encode-hebrew-string-nsstring-into-a-unicode-format-in-order-to-send-as

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format `%uxxxx` is a [non-standard implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations) of percent encoding and is not supported by `NSString`s `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:`. If you need to handle these encodings you will need to either find 3rd party code that can do this for you or implement your own solution.